# Как заменить элементы побочной диагонали? С++ \ С

Tags: c++, c

Задача : Заменить элементы побочной диагонали матрицы n*n максимальными элементами каждого столбца данной матрицы.  Элементы матрицы - отрицательные числа.

пример показан для первого столбца матрицы:

```
float temp[n];
float arr_max[n];
float arr[n][n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 9 - 10;
    }
}

float max_el;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    temp[i] = arr[i][0];
}

max_el = temp[0];
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    max_el = max_el > temp[j] ? max_el : temp[j];
}
arr_max[0] = max_el;

printf("\nYour array is");

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("\t%.2f", temp[i]);
}

printf("\nMax el of row is %.2f", arr_max[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает распространить этот пример на все столбцы? Пример не фонтан, лишние сущности вводит для копий столбцов и максимумов, всё это не требуется хранить.

Я оставил вам написать строчку самостоятельно.

```
for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
    float max_el = arr[0][col];
    for (int row = 1; row < n; row++) 
         max_el = max_el > arr[row][col] ? max_el : arr[row][col];

    //и тут назначаем max_el - максимум в столбце col
    //элементу побочной диагонали в данном столбце
    //дотумкайте, какие у него будут индексы
}
```

Comment: arr[col][n-1-col] = max_el;  // так???

Comment: Наоборот  же индексы: `arr[n-1-col][col]`